# Which function matches this shape?

Tags: curves, algebraic-curves, data-analysis

I'm trying to find a function that matches the following shape.

[image]

My first attempt was with a cosine function

$$ f(x) = a\cos(b x)$$

which yields the following result:

[image]

What modification of the cosine function could help to make it better fit the required shape? Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

---

EDIT: the raw data is available in csv format [here](https://gist.github.com/jakobgreenfeld/bf7f0a9de68da610129d0fefe6b5802d).

---

EDIT 2:

Simple polynomial functions do not seem to yield better results.

Order 2:
[image]

Order 3:

[image]

Order 5:

[image]

For $f(x) = C-Ae^{bx}$ as suggested by @FranCruz I find

[image]

Comment: My first guess wouldn't be a trigonometric function unless the data is known to be from a periodic system. It may be something less exciting like a low-degree polynomial.

Comment: See [non linear least squares](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares). A software implementation might automatically fit this for you

Comment: @Graviton Thanks! I actually started with a polynomial fit but the results haven't been very good. I'll attach the corresponding graphs in the questions above.

Comment: @IdioticShrike I know how to do non-linear least squares fit. What I'm looking for is the function to fit.

Comment: What if you try something like $f(x) = C-Ae^{bx}$, with $A,b \geq 0$, and fit it via a least-square method?

Comment: For a visual intuition: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-3*e%5E%282*x%29).

Comment: @FranCruz Thanks! I added a graph with my fit result to the question above. It clearly matches the shape of the data better at larger values of x but is worse at low x values

Comment: Maybe try with $f(x) = C-Ae^{b(x-x_0)}$. New parameter $x_0$ will be able to move the curve horizontally. That might result in a better fit.

Comment: @FranCruz Just tried it but the best fit still looks very similar.

Comment: Where does the data come from? That might help

Comment: @FranCruz  I'm trying to understand the relationship between the rank and the number of installs in different app stores. The data here shows the Log(rank) over the Log(number of installs) for Wordpress plugins. I want to find a function that matches the general shape and then see if it applies to other app stores as well. I also added a link to the raw data above.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no intuition in that field. I'll let you know if some other reasonable curve comes to mind.

Comment: Would a piece wise solution be good for you? You could stitch together the cosine with the order five polynomial and get a very strong approximation

Comment: @IdioticShrike That's a great idea thanks! Will give it a shot.

Comment: Have you tried an ellipse (or equivalently, a rational Bezier curve)?

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct looking at that data was 'parabola' (quadratic polynomial). It looks like a concave down parabola. I think you can get a good degree 2 polynomial fit for this data.

Comment: I added the result of a degree 2 polynomial fit to the question above.

Comment: Are you using least squares for the fit? Because that doesn't look like a good fit for the left side of the graph (and I think it could be fit much better on the left with little change on the right).